# How to write the response from nestjs exception filters using nestfastify

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, fastify, nestjs-config

I have an issue in writing custom http response from nestjs exception filters

I'm using the nest fastify one (not the express)

I'm creating custom exception filters that catch UserNotFoundException as follows:

```js
@Catch(UserNotFoundException)
export class UserNotFoundExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: UserNotFoundException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const errorResponse = new ErrorResponse<string[]>();
    const response = host.switchToHttp().getResponse();
    errorResponse.message = 'unauthorized exception'
    errorResponse.errors = [
      'invalid username or pass'
    ];
    response.status(401).json(errorResponse)

  }
}
```

i keep getting response.status(...).json() is not a function.

```js
[Nest] 5400   - 05/17/2020, 00:27:26   [ExceptionsHandler] response.status(...).json is not a function +82263ms
TypeError: response.status(...).json is not a function
```

I know that i had to specify
the type of that response to some type of response writer (e.g : Response from express).

i try to  import that  **Response** object from express, and update type of **response** variable to Response(express) like following:

```js
import {Response} from 'express';
```

```js
 const response = host.switchToHttp().getResponse<Response>();
```

and everything running smoothly.

But i dont want to add some express thing to my application, i just want to go with nestjs fastify.
Do you guys know any class that can replace this Response obejct from express?
Or if  you another smarter way to tackle this, it will help also

thank everyone

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using `Fastify` you need to use the `FastifyReply<ServerResponse>` type from `fastify` and the `http` packages. Fastify itself does not have a `json` method on the reply object, but it does have a `.send()` method that will `JSON.stringify()` an object if it is given an object.

While the project may *build* if you use the `Response` object from `express`, you'll probably get a runtime error about `response.status().json is not a function`. The below should work properly

```js
import { FastifyReply } from 'fastify';

@Catch(UserNotFoundException)
export class UserNotFoundExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: UserNotFoundException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const errorResponse = new ErrorResponse<string[]>();
    const response = host.switchToHttp().getResponse<FastifyReply<ServerResponse>>();
    errorResponse.message = 'unauthorized exception'
    errorResponse.errors = [
      'invalid username or pass'
    ];
    response.status(401).send(errorResponse)

  }
}
```

Overall, Nest is a **wrapper** for Express and Fastify, and most of the docs are pertinent to Express when talking about library specific options (like Request and Response). You should reference [Fastify's documentation](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest) when it comes to library specific approaches.

Comment: By using ServerResponse I'm getting the following error - Type 'ServerResponse' does not satisfy the constraint 'RawServerBase'.  I succeed only when it is a server from HTTP. any other suggestion please?

Comment: @avisiboni  It defaults to http.ServerResponse so to get this you would only need to do something like

const response = host.switchToHttp().getResponse<FastifyReply>();

Comment: I can't figure out where ErrorResponse is coming from.

Comment: `ErrorResponse` is a class specific to OP.